# Buttons having different id to call the same js function

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
foreach ($_SESSION['songlist']['items'] as $key => $value1) {
    $id = $value1['id']['videoId'];
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

    echo "<br>";
    echo "<iframe src='//www.youtube.com/embed/$id?enablejsapi=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen id='video'></iframe>";echo "<br>";
    echo '<div id="Added" style="display:none;">ADDED!</div>';
    echo "<form id='demo' method='POST' action=''><button type='button' name='button' id='$id' method='POST' onclick='Count($id)'>Add to playlist</button></form>";
}
```

This is my button

I want to have a separate counter for different buttons using js onclick function.

Comment: Why are you using `session_start()` every loop? You should only need to use it once.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! But I am having problem in starting the counter from 0 for different buttons.

Comment: you cannot legitimately have multiple DOM Elements with the same ID - they all have to be unique. You can however use a `dataset` attribute such as `data-id` with the value of the php variable `$id` and use js to calculate whatever using that

Comment: For every button inside the loop there is an unique value for every id. I am running a script on clicking a button. Please help to reset the counter to 0 for different buttons.

Comment: This is the script                                                                                 <script type="text/javascript">
var cnt = 0;
function Count(id)  {

    cnt = parseInt(cnt) + parseInt(1);
    alert(cnt);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "ADDED! ";


}
</script>

Comment: I think, in script you have to make associative array of cnt, and add key as id with count. like suppose id = 1 count=0 array("1"=>0)... then search array if id is present in array or not if present then increment id value by 1 other wise add new id in that array

Comment: Thanks!! Found out a new way using mysql database. But I'm surely gonna try this way too.